# ubuntu dual boot with windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

I have a windows 8 hp laptop with windows 8 pre installed. I installed ubuntu 12.04 lts alongside windows 8. The grub menu to choose the os to boot did not appear. So I downloaded and installed easy bcd. On reboot it presented me with the option to boot either windows or ubuntu. If I choose windows everything is fine, but when I choose the ubuntu option, all I see is  grub black screen prompt waiting for command. Please help coz I am a novice and I have searched the web but couldn't find anything so useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a software called [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). This should be the easiest way for repairing.

Usually, this will result in a grub which can both boot Linux and Windows.